# Problemin getting correct query result in asp.net using join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am learning ASP.net and I have come to the point that I want to insert, update, delete records in a database.

Currently I am trying to read out values out of 2 tables using "join" but when I display the results in a grid the Foreign Key values are still like : 2, 1, 2,... Instead I want them to be to coresponding words.

This is the current query I am using: 
`from p in dc.Personeels join a in dc.Afdelingens on p.fk_personeel_afdeling equals a.pk_afdeling_id select p`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by corresponding words? are the numbers 2,1,2.. ids or what? please elaborate with your table structures, so we can understand your problem

Comment: Yes those numbers are indeed ID's 

Table structures:
tblPersoneel
 -pk_personeel_id
 -personeel_voornaam
 -personeel_achternaam
 -fk_personeel_afdeling

tblAfdeling
 -pk_afdeling_id
 -afdeling_naam

So I want to have the field "afdeling_naam" instead of those ID's

Comment: first of all its not sql its linq that you are using. Second thing the query is selecting all the data only from dc.Personeels table and not from the dc.Afdelingens.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title :)
How do I make it select also from dc.Afdelings?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
var query = from p in dc.Personeels 
            join a in dc.Afdelingens on p.fk_personeel_afdeling equals a.pk_afdeling_id 
            select new 
            {
                id = p.id, // your id from table dc.Personeels 
                name = a.name // Name from table dc.Afdelingens
            } into x
            select x;
```